# Javascript:Replacing a but not the a in ab

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering if it was possible to replace certain strings but not others that contain the same value in javascript. For example, say I had the text `A AB` and wanted to replace only the standalone `A` but not the A in AB. (Note: I know that I could do this manually in this case, but I plan on using scenarios like this throughout large blocks of text) Is there an algorithm or built in js command for doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regular expression with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
var str = 'A AB';
str = str.replace(/\bA\b/g, '');
```

Comment: Note that "word boundaries" include characters like hyphen (-), so A-B is two words.

Comment: Ok one more question. (By the way I'm not that good with regex so please bear with me) Why doesn't this code work:
`var x = 'A',
    str = 'A AB';
    str = str.replace(RegExp('\b'+x+'\b', 'g'), '');`

Comment: @Kpower It doesn't work because the backslash in `'\b'` is being interpreted as a control character for the string. If you want a literal backslash within a quoted string, you need to escape it. Try this: `var x = 'A', str = 'A AB'; str = str.replace(RegExp('\\b'+x+'\\b', 'g'), '');`

Comment: Would it be posible to replacethe BAB in CBABAC but not the BAB in DABABCC

Comment: @Kpower: Probably but there are some ambiguities in your example. Probably better to start a new question for that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using regular expressions in javascript,

```
string = string.replace(/A/, "AB")
```

will replace the charecters which occurs for the first time.

```
string = string.replace(/A/g, "AB")
```

will replace the all occurances of "A" with "AB"

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to replace just the stand-alone letter "A", then you may want something like:

```
var re = /(^|\s)a(\s|$)/ig;
```

Then you can do:

```
var s = 'A ab a ba a-b b-a a:v b a';
alert(s.replace(re, 'Z')); // ZabZba a-b b-a a:v bZ
```

Note that this also removes white space arounding the letter.

#### Edit

To keep whitespace:

```
alert( s.replace(re, '$1Z$2') ); // Z ab Z ba a-b b-a a:v b Z
```

Comment: Any way to do this without removing whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to others answers, you could also write:
string=string.replace(/a(?=\s)/,"");
(?= means it will replace 'a' only if the **next** characers are space/tab, etc..
you could also write different regex instead of \s if you need other condition (only the 'a' will match ,not the condition regex in the (?=...)

for your other question in the comment(in Asaph answer)you can write:

str = str.replace(RegExp("\\b"+x+"\\b",'g'),'');