# Javascript:Replacing letters within certain phrases only

Tags: javascript, regex

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681822/javascriptreplacing-a-but-not-the-a-in-ab) I was asked to form a new question with one of my comments so here I am. I was wondering if it was possible to replace a phrase within certain words only. Eg: Replacing the `BAB` in `CBABAC` but not the `BAB` in `DABABCC` Thanks!

Comment: on basis of what logic?. any post or pre condition?

Comment: see Lookahead and Lookbehind Assertions [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/advanced-regular-expression-tips-and-techniques/)

Comment: It is apparent from both of these questions that you need to read up on Regular Expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: @diEcho Lookbehind doesn't work in javascript.

Comment: @AlexW with all due respect, if everyone was just to read up on their topic, stackoverflow wouldn't exist at all. I have read up on regular expressions but considering their breadth and number of operators, it can be very difficult to understand IMO. That being said, I did look at your link and am reading it right now, so thanks for it.

Comment: @Kpower There is a website that helps you learn them with a hands-on approach: http://regexone.com/

Comment: I'm uncertain of what exactly your question is. You doesn't explain the key difference between the two words you're trying to replace. I think if you were to clarify the requires for a replacement to occur a better answer could be given. Ex: replace BAB in words where BAB is preceded by a C such as in CBABAC. Or Ex: replace BAB in words where BAB is appended by a A such as in CBABAC.

Comment: @travis I was talked about having the same phrase within two different words, but only replacing that phrase when in one of the words when you know the two words and which one to replace... if that makes sense >.>

Answer (score 2):

**Use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):**

```
BAB(?=AC)
```

**Explanation**

```
"BAB" +      // Match the characters “BAB” literally
"(?=" +      // Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   "AC" +       // Match the characters “AC” literally
")"
```

or

```
BAB(?!CC)
```

**Explanation**

```
"BAB" +      // Match the characters “BAB” literally
"(?!" +      // Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   "CC" +       // Match the characters “CC” literally
")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the basis is for the logic of the replacement, so this is a generalised answer.

As some have mentioned, you could use a lookahead, but one of the major annoyances of JavaScript is that it doesn't natively support lookbehinds, so you have only half a solution there.

A common workaround for the lack of look-behind is to match (rather than anchor to) what comes before the bit you're interested in, then reinsert it in the callback.

Let's say I want to replace all instances of `foo` with `bar`, where it is preceded and proceded by a number.

```
var str = 'foo 1foo1 foo2';
console.log(str.replace(/(\d)foo(?=\d)/g, function($0, $1) {
    return $1+'bar';
})); //foo 1bar1 foo1
```

So I use a lookahead for the easy part, and a callback to compensate for the lack of lookbehind.

There *are* implementations of lookbehind in JS, **[including one I wrote](http://www.mitya.co.uk/scripts/Simulating-REGEX-look-behinds-JavaScript-164)**, where a positive or negative lookbehind is passed as an extra parameter. Using that, this would get the same result as the above:

```
console.log(str.replace2(/foo(?=\d)/g, 'bar', '(?<=\\d)'));
```